# What happens with Krypto when Superman becomes an adult?

Tags: dc, superman

When Superman is a boy, Krypto is always around but never appears when Superman is adult.

What is the reason that Krypto no longer appears?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was no canonical tidy end, but he died in pre-Crisis [Action Comics #583](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_583), via the Kryptonite Man:

[image]

This was a [flashback/retcon](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_583), likely to address the lack[s] of closure.  Assist to @KHW: "This version of Krypto (Earth-One), including all history and corresponding appearances, was erased from existence following the collapse of the Multiverse in the 1985-86 Crisis on Infinite Earths limited series and is now considered apocryphal." - from Krypto's Wikia [article](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Krypto_%28Earth-One%29).

Comment: Perhaps it should also be mentioned that per [Krypto's page](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Krypto_%28Earth-One%29) "This version of Krypto (Earth-One), including all history and corresponding appearances, was erased from existence following the collapse of the Multiverse in the 1985-86 Crisis on Infinite Earths limited series and is now considered apocryphal."

Comment: @KHW I thought 'non-canon' was enough.  But yeah, sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Well, that's a.. bizarre issue.. Non-canon v.s. 'retro-actively deleted from history' by a canon occurrence... Said differently -- "It was canon, and now is non-canon by virtue of a change that occurred as part of the canon." Enough to make your head spin.... :)